# Is this ConcurrentLinkedQueue/wait/notify algorithm correct?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, java.util.concurrent

I know that typically for producer/consumer pairs like this, a blocking queue should be used. What I want here is only to understand better memory consistency in Java, interaction between concurrent data structures and locks, and also what is exactly the imprecision when determining the size of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

The question is, does the algorithm below assure, that anything produced is consumed, as it would in the case of a plain non-thread safe queue? Note: I ran it several times and it always was the case.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class Produce extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(Main.queue) {
            Main.queue.add(1);
            Main.queue.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
public class Consume extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(Main.queue) {
            while(true) {
                while(!Main.queue.isEmpty()) {
                    Main.queue.poll();
                    System.out.println("consumed");
                }
                System.out.println("empty");
                try {
                    Main.queue.wait();
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> queue =
            new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Consume()).start();
        (new Produce()).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your queue is thread safe, there is no need for the wait and notify.

Comment: That's true, but I use `wait()` for performance reasons.

Comment: To answer your question, yes the consumer will see all updates, but I don't see how this would improve performance vs using the queue the way it was supposed to be used...

Comment: `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is not blocking, `poll()` returns null if the queue is empty. Without `wait()`, the consumer thread would be in a busy loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes.  The consumer will see all of the updates.

However:

1. This is not a sensible implementation.  It looks like you are using the polling approach with  wait / notify so that you don't need a busy loop to wait for the queue to become nonempty.  But a better (simpler, more efficient) approach would be to use a `BlockingQueue` instead and use the blocking `get()` method.

   For what it is worth, you are negating any *possible* scalability advantages of using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` by using the queue object as a mutex to do wait / notify signalling.  (This would also apply if you used a different object as the mutex.  The problem is the mutual exclusion!)
2. If you are going to do it this way (for whatever reason), a `notify()` would be preferable to a `notifyAll()`.  Only one consumer is going to be able to consume that (single) element you added to the queue.  Waking up all of the consumers is unnecessary.
3. It is not a good idea to extend `Thread`.  A better way is to put your business logic into a `Runnable` (or a lambda) which you pass as a `Thread` constructor parameter.  Read: ["implements Runnable" vs "extends Thread" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/)

---

You also were interested in:

> ... what is exactly the imprecision when determining the size of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

The answer to that is in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#size--) for `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`:

> *"Beware that, unlike in most collections, this method is NOT a constant-time operation. Because of the asynchronous nature of these queues, determining the current number of elements requires an O(n) traversal."*
>
> *"Additionally, if elements are added or removed during execution of this method, the returned result may be inaccurate. Thus, this method is typically not very useful in concurrent applications."*

In other words, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` *counts* the queue elements, and does not give an accurate answer if elements are being added and removed at the same time.